# Live tracking of shipment in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipment-tracking

How to configure live tracking in magento 2 CE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Live tracking" is available in Magento 1.x and 2.x by way of the transactional email. When adding a tracking number to a shipment the email that follows contains a link to the shipping module Tracking Popup action. This loads the popup.

To call this "live tracking" is a bit of a misnomer but if you utilize the API of a shipment provider like UPS or Fedex you will likely be able to click through to the tracking page for that API.

Comment: can you please provide steps of how  can i utilize that API?

Comment: It's not an API. It's a feature of the Magento shipping module in the platform - a windowed view into the tracking information as received from the shipment provider.

Comment: @philwinkle I am using, ups, usps, fedex, My live tracking popup window show nothing, but courier website shows every tracking details.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Utilize the API of the carrier, if the carrier offers an API and your carrier module supports it. In that case you need to have an active account with specific permissions to each carrier to use their API. Usually your carrier module asks for API credentials in it's configuration settings.
2. Use a module which consumes a tracking API, which supports several carriers.
   For example: [ShipTracker](https://breakdesigns.net/extensions/magento/shiptracker)