# Magento2.2 what do people use for shipment tracking

Tags: magento2.2, shipment-tracking

I am wondering what others use on there magento 2.x site to allow customers to enter in an order number and view the USPS shipment tracking info. such as if an order is out for delivery and or when/where it was last scanned in by usps.

On our Magento 1.9 site we use to have a plugin that enabled customers to do this and it would then grab the usps tracking number automatically from an order and show all the transit information. however i can not find any magento2.x compatible plugins. So wondering what others do ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggested is the Magento 2 blue dart extension for tracking.

https://www.softprodigy.com/store/bluedart-shipping

For Woocommerce general the best is also the blue dart for tracking

https://codecanyon.net/item/blue-dart-shipping-integration-with-woocommerce/12415560

Comment: Thank you. I ended up building a custom shipment tracking script for magento 2

Comment: Seems duplicate to that: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120800/live-tracking-of-shipment-in-magento-2

Comment: @Jayreis can you post that script in an answer. or can you please share that I need the same one.